# Android SQLite composite primary key. Should I still implement BaseColumns

Tags: android, sqlite

If I want to implement a many to many relationship in a two column SQLite table in Android like so:

```
CREATE TABLE favorites (
  user_key, 
  bar_key, 
  FOREIGN KEY (user_key) references User(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (bar_key) references Bar(bar_id), 
  PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2)
);
```

Should my Table classes in my Contract class still implement BaseColumns? In my mind, that would be an unnecessary primary key for this table

```
public static final class FavoritesEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
            BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_FAVORITES).build();

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
            "vnd.android.cursor.dir/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_FAVORITES;
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
            "vnd.android.cursor.item/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_FAVORITES;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "favorites";

    public static final String COLUMN_USER_KEY = "user_key";
    public static final String COLUMN_BAR_KEY = "bar_key";

    public static Uri buildFavoritesUri(long id) {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to implement `buildFavoritesUri()` with a single ID, or not?

Comment: No I don't, but I was confused how I would format the id for a Uri, which is based upon a composite primary key. Would it be something like: /favorites/{key1}/{key2}

Comment: Use whatever works best for this interface. That format is the obvious solution.